# sandbox stub different stub withargs and callback

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stub

i would like stub one function and return a different value with different args  and this fuction use one callback

ex:

```
function saop (){
 saop.get('car',"http://webservice.com",function (err, result) {});
// (null, {car:"car"}) 
 saop.get('house',"http://webservice.com",function (err, result) {});
// (null, {house:"house"})
}
```

i'm try use this :

```
var stub = sandbox.stub(saop, 'get');

stub.onCall(0).returns(null, {car:"car"});
stub.onCall(1).returns(null, {house:"house"});
```

but stub return always null, {car:"car"} 
i'm also try use :

```
var stub = sandbox.stub(saop, 'get');
 stub.withArgs('car').returns(null, {car:"car"});
 stub.withArgs('house').returns(null, {house:"house"});
```

but the stub return null.

can you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that the stub should call the callback with those values, you should use [`yields`](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.4.1/stubs/#stubyieldsarg1-arg2-) instead of `returns` (the former will call the first function argument it receives, in this case the callback, with the fixtures; the latter will actually make the function *return* those values, which in case of callbacks isn't very useful):

```
stub.onCall(0).yields(null, {car:"car"});
stub.onCall(1).yields(null, {house:"house"});
```